# Need assistance with PHP curl call

Tags: php, curl

Hello:  I am trying to do an API call using curl_init; have made some good progress but seem to be stuck...

we have an interface (swagger) that allows us to do the curl call and test it which works:  here is the curl commands from that:

```
curl -X POST --header "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" 
--header "Accept: application/json" 
--header "Authorization: Bearer xxxxx-xxxxxx- xxxxx-xxxxxxx" 
-d "username=xxxxxxxx39%40gmail.com&password=xxxx1234"        "http://xxxxxxxxx-xx-xx-201-115.compute-1.amazonaws.com:xxxx/api/users"
```

here is my attempt to do the same call in PHP code:

```
$json = '{
"username": "xmanxxxxxx%40gmail.com",
"password": "xxxx1234"
}';


  $gtoken='xxxxxx-xxxxxx-xxx-xxxxxxxx';

$token_string="Authorization: Bearer ".$gtoken;


$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
CURLOPT_URL => 'http://exx-ccc-vvv-vvvv.compute-1.amazonaws.com:xxxx/api/users', //URL to the API
CURLOPT_POST => true,
CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $json,
CURLOPT_HEADER => true, // Instead of the "-i" flag
CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array('Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded','Accept: application/json',$token_string) 

));

curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,TRUE);

$resp = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
```

I am getting a response code "500" which makes me think that there is something wrong with my input.  So I am wondering if anyone can help with this...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your command line code, you post a standard URL encoded data string using `-d "username=xxxxxxxx39%40gmail.com&password=xxxx1234"` but in PHP you are creating a JSON string and sending it as a single post field (not properly URL encoded).

I think this is what you need:

```
$data = array(
    'username' => 'xmanxxxxxx@gmail.com',
    'password' => 'xxxx1234',
);

$data = http_build_query($data); // convert array to urlencoded string

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
```

As far as I can tell the rest of the code looks fine.

Also, you don't explicitly need to set the `Content-Type` header, cURL will do this for you when you pass a string to `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS`.  It will set it to `multipart/form-data` if you pass an array to `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS`.  But having it doesn't hurt anything either.